# SSH with Chilkat in VB6; but maybe generaly

Tags: ssh, vb6, chilkat

I have written an application for SSH, but the originally used library is no longer developed and has old methods of encryption. Thus, it is not usable for contemporary devices. I am looking for alternatives and I found Chilkat.

I am able to start connecting to the device (Cisco switch for instance), but communication behaves in strange ways.

The basic principle of my program is based on talking client (my program) and server (Cisco switch). After the login is done, I get prompt saying that I would get into priviledged mode by command enable. I recongize this need by sign > at the end of prompt. I send command enable and awaiting prompt Password: After I get it I a send password. I am using two components and timer in this time :

`success = ssh.ChannelSendString(channelNum, commandToSend & Chr(13), "ansi")`

and

`auxStr = ssh.GetReceivedText(channelNum, "ansi")`

when I get word Password: in receiving text, I send password string  like a commandToSend

but I get % Access denied

I am pretty sure that the password is OK; it seems like one extra enter is sent via connection, because during next returned text is this message :

Translating "passwordString"...domain server (255.255.255.255)

it indicates that passwordString was sent into the switch after message
% Access denied
not like an answer to Password: prompt.

I made debugging in the code to see what my program is sending to switch, but everything seems to be correct. Maybe some mistake in chilkat component ?

Has anybody similar experience ? Or explanation of this behaviour and advice how to solve it, please ?

Comment: You are sending chr(13), generally text protocols use CRLF [chr(13)chr(10)], I would try that.

Answer (score 1):

Send the "enable" command (or just "ena") followed by a single CHR(13).  Then get the output from the SSH server, which should be the "Password:" prompt.  Then send the password followed by the CHR(13).   Then get the output.  The send each command terminated by a single CHR(13) and get the output after each command.